# How to inspect temporary variables of VueJS component methods in production build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, variables, vue-component, devtools

My VueJS components have to be built as main.js + main.js.map and run from IIS server with Asp.Net Core.
From Chrome DevTools' console, I can set breakpoints on any method of Vue components. But when I type a var variable on the DevTools console, it shows the error: 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined**
The Local pane shows the variable's value. But I cannot run variable.length for a string.
Any insight is appreciated.